# Alfresco Activiti - Make Field read only for specific group/task

Tags: alfresco, activiti

I'm very new to Alfresco, I have created a workflow with tasks and user groups.
Now I want to know if there's a way to show the same form to a different user group  with some read-only fields. 
There were many answers on how to do it with code, I just want to know if there's a way of doing it in the UI level (From the app)

Comment: IIRC, if you're using custom control then you can check the current user belongs to the specified group or not then you should be able to update the read-only mode. This is an idea, but never tried anywhere.

Comment: Can we update read-only mode for specific fields only?

Comment: Can we do it without code?

Comment: on which control? I can give a try.

Comment: what do you mean by ""which control" ?

Comment: like textbox, dropdown, textarea

Comment: did you tried adding javacript to your fields? try to change to the `type` of the field from js based on a list of users. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this, without writing code, but I can share my suggestions, so that, some experts share their views also.

*I can see, there are 2 options.*

1. Write custom control and apply your logic (Only share side changes  and may be less change in Repo side[Based on your business logic]).
2. Create mulitple workflow forms and apply your logic in runtime and display the form dynamically.

**Option 1:**

You can refer the `textfield.ftl` in `tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\site-webscripts\org\alfresco\components\form\controls\textfield.ftl`

While generating the textbox, Share is checking whether it has disabled option or not. If so, it adds the `disabled="true"` attribute.

```
<label for="${fieldHtmlId}">${field.label?html}:<#if field.mandatory><span class="mandatory-indicator">${msg("form.required.fields.marker")}</span></#if></label>
      <input id="${fieldHtmlId}" name="${field.name}" tabindex="0"
        /* Other code lines are removed to make it simple to understand */
             <#if field.disabled && !(field.control.params.forceEditable?? && field.control.params.forceEditable == "true")>disabled="true"</#if> />
      <@formLib.renderFieldHelp field=field />
```

You can also apply similar logic to achieve for your case, but you need to write some code.

```
<label for="${fieldHtmlId}">${field.label?html}:<#if field.mandatory><span class="mandatory-indicator">${msg("form.required.fields.marker")}</span></#if></label>
      <input id="${fieldHtmlId}" name="${field.name}" tabindex="0"
        /* Other code lines are removed to make it simple to understand */
        /* We need to determine, how we will be bringing the condition over here */
            <#if <YOUR_CONDITION> =="true")>disabled="true"</#if> />
      <@formLib.renderFieldHelp field=field />
```

**Option 2**

Share config changes.

```
<!-- Edit form With All controls enabled -->
<config evaluator="task-type" condition="example:Form1AllEnabled">
 ..
</config>

<!-- Edit form With specific controls disabled -->
<config evaluator="task-type" condition="example:Form1FewControlsDisabled">
 ..
</config>
```

Workflow (bpmn file)side changes

```
<userTask id="form1" name="User Update Task" activiti:assignee="${bpm_assignee.properties.userName}" activiti:formKey="${userUpdateTaskFormKey}">
</userTask>
```

You need to create a delegate and dynamically update `userUpdateTaskFormKey` variable in the execution level.

```
@Override
public void execute(final DelegateExecution delegate) throws Exception
{
    String userUpdateTaskFormKey = "example:Form1FewControlsDisabled"; //Keeping it default
    String currentUserName  = authenticationService.getCurrentUserName();
    //Apply user business logic ....
    if (user....your condition)
    {
       userUpdateTaskFormKey =  "example:Form1AllEnabled";
    }

}
```